# Install Ubuntu on a separate hard drive?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot-loader

I am running Windows 7. I would like to dual-boot Ubuntu, but minimize risk of something going wrong. In the past I have encountered an issue with the bootloader getting corrupted and having to reformat the whole drive. The magic bootloader recovery tools did not work. Thus, I want to install Ubuntu on a *separate* drive.

My question is, is it possible to have multiple bootloaders? If install Ubuntu on a clean drive while not having any other drives connected, can I choose which OS to boot by using the motherboard's boot priority (i.e., place Windows disk higher to boot that)?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [WUBI](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer)  if you want to minimise the risk.